# Linq on nested Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a dictionary of dictionary and I want to find a value from inner dictionary by Linq .

My code is:

```
private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>> SubCategoryDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>>();
  private Dictionary<int, string> BGA_Dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
  private Dictionary<int, string> Lead3D_Dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
  private Dictionary<int, string> Lead2D_Dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
  private Dictionary<int, string> Leadless_Dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
  private Dictionary<int, string> PIC_Dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

In my constructor I have all values like this:--

```
BGA_Dictionary.Add(1, "Body_Measurement");
     BGA_Dictionary.Add(2, "Ball_Measurement");
     SubCategoryDictionary.Add("BGA", BGA_Dictionary);

     Lead3D_Dictionary.Add(1, "Component_Height");
     Lead3D_Dictionary.Add(2, "Rib_Measurement");
     SubCategoryDictionary.Add("Package", Lead3D_Dictionary);

     Lead2D_Dictionary.Add(1, "Dirt_Inspection");
     Lead2D_Dictionary.Add(2, "Half_Cut_Inspection");
     SubCategoryDictionary.Add("Mark", Lead2D_Dictionary);
```

Now I need a Lambda expression which will give me something like :
when key of SubCategoryDictionary ="Mark" and key of Lead3D_Dictionary =2 then I should get "Rib_Measurement".

I tried with following code :

```
string q = (from cls in SubCategoryDictionary
                 from s in cls.Value
                 where cls.Key == "Mark" && s.Key == 3
                 select s.Value).FirstOrDefault();


foreach (var a in q)
     {

     }
```

This above code works but I need in lambda expression. So if someone help me in formation of Lambda formation. It will be of great help.

Thanks.

Comment: are you talking about `SubCategoryDictionary["Mark"][2]`?

Comment: @vasily.sib I was trying like string q = (from cls in SubCategoryDictionary
                     from s in cls.Value
                     where cls.Key == "Mark" && s.Key == 3
                     select s.Value).FirstOrDefault(); and this gives me result. Just can not form a Lambda expression out of this. Could you please help me on Lambda formation.

Comment: your linq is just accessing single element by keys. Why do you ever think you need a lambda for this? Anyway, here it is: `Func<string,int,string> lambda = (k1, k2) => SubCategoryDictionary[k1][k2];`

Comment: @vasily.sib how to mark your answer as the answer . Thanks for this . please post it in answer  section. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you ever need a lambda for accessing a dictionary by keys, but here it is:

```
Func<string,int,string> lambda = (k1, k2) => SubCategoryDictionary[k1][k2];
```

Now you can invoke it with `var subCategory = lambda("Mark", 2);`

Answer (score -1):

I guess below code should get you the value you are trying to get.

```
        var lead3 = SubCategoryDictionary["Mark"].SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == 2).Value;
```

The idea is to use the Key of the first dictionary and get the value of it than filter it with SingleOrDefault method by providing a key to the inner dictionary value you are interested in.

Hope this helps

Comment: Why use `SingleOrDefault`?

Comment: @Farrukh Manzoor you have mentioned SubCategoryDictionary["Mark"] which is not linq . I was trying something like string q = (from cls in SubCategoryDictionary
                     from s in cls.Value
                     where cls.Key == "Mark" && s.Key == 3
                     select s.Value).FirstOrDefault(); it is giving me output when I iterate over foreach but I need in a Lambda format way

Comment: @NewProgrammer Using LINQ to do a lookup on a `Dictionary` is foolhardy. A `Dictionary` is **incredibly good** at key lookups. Let it do its job. When I want to drive somewhere, I don't get the kids in the card and then **push the car**. No, I drive it - because that is what it is good at.

Comment: @mjwills nice comment . will follow.